# Width of <a> elements in dropdown menu fit the parent <li> (HTML list)

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu made with HTML and CSS. I always was fighting with items in the menu, because almost none of them had width 100% of [li], like on the image:

[image: Elements in dropdown menu]

**Just want to make second** (and third element too) **to fit the li** - be the same width as the firs element ([li] and [ul] width are automatically the same as the widest element on list)

Here is my CSS Code: http://pastebin.com/tNfYmSpJ

HTML: http://pastebin.com/mvBRietS

I was using this tutorial: http://www.handy-html.com/create-a-simple-css-dropdown-menu/
But modified it a little bit. I tried to get the same width of [a] elements on list (in [li] tags), but never succeed :P
Is there simple way to force links a to be fit 100% of parent [li] width? I know there can be set fixed width of [a], but it is not the solution I am looking for :/

Comment: For future reference, please post your code here, rather than linking to it on JSFiddle or Pastebin. Also, post your HTML code, please.

Comment: When I pasted code here, there was an alert telling me that most of my message is code and I should write more text content... so I pasted links to it. But thanks for advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `a` element is by default an [inline-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) element. To make it a [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) element, change its `display` property in accordance.

For example:

```
a {display:block;}
```

And based on the example you've linked to, you're most likely looking to do:

```
#mainmenu li a {
    ...
    display:block
}
```

Comment: In my CSS I have ".menu a" definition with "diplay: block". My UL have .menu class - so it should work... but effect is as on the screen attached.
When checking an element with Opera Developer Tools, there is ".menu a" applied for these links in sub-menu. Magic or something else that id don't work?

Comment: @Szorstki It's difficult to debug this way, you better provide a live example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Now that you've narrowed it down, my guess would be that the `li` parents are limiting the width of the `a` elements, since they are set to `display:inline-block;`

Comment: It was all about "float: none;" in the drop-down :)

Comment: @Szorstki It's the same thing basically. Giving an `inline` element a `float` value automatically applies `display:block` to it. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float)

Comment: I know that, but didn't knew float impacts on the width :)